# Webpack bundle served by express server - can't find bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Hi this is my express server which i'm trying to setup to use with webpack.

```
const Server = require('./server.js')
const path = require('path')
const port = (process.env.PORT || 3001)
const app = Server.app()

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  const webpack = require('webpack')
  const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
  const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')
  const config = require('./webpack.config.js')
  const compiler = webpack(config)

  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))
  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: path.join(__dirname, '/build')
  }))
}

app.listen(port)
  console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
```

**./app.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')

module.exports = {
  app: function () {
    const app = express();
    const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, '/build/index.html');
    const publicPath = express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/build'));

    app.use('/build', publicPath);
    app.get('/', function (_, res) { res.sendFile(indexPath) });

    return app;
  }
}
```

**./server.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '/build');

var config = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname,'app/main.js'),
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/build/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/, query: { presets: ['es2015', 'react']}},
      { test: /\.sass$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'] },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?prefix=img/&limit=5000" },
      { test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'babel!svg-react' }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

**./webpack.config.js**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**./build/index.html**

When I run `node app.js` it finds the `index.html` page but i'm get a 404 error 'cannot find bundle.js' im sure somewhere im pointing to the wrong directory but i cannot seem to work it out!

Comment: Where do you keep your `bundle.js`?. Is it inside your `BUILD_DIR` (or) somewhere else?

Comment: bundle.js is supposed to be output by webpack to the BUILD_DIR (./build)

Comment: In that case in your `var config` declaration your `filename` should be changed as `filename: './bundle.js',` right?

Comment: Since i passed it a path it should be fine but i tried anyway but nope still nothing

Comment: Okay, One final question, Is your `build.html` and your `bundle.js` files residing in the same directory?

Comment: My index.html file is in the build folder where the bundle.js file should be. In case its relevant the components for the app itself are in a different folder "./app/"

Comment: When you run webpack do you get an error.

Comment: Nope no error when i run webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're serving `build/index.html` on `/` it looks for the file `/bundle.js` (the directory you start your server from), which clearly doesn't exist. With your Webpack config you would create the file `/build/bundle.js`, if you ran Webpack.

Now here is where the `webpack-dev-middleware` comes in. Instead of creating that file, it serves the bundle from memory whenever the according path is hit. All you need to do, is tell the middleware that you want to serve the bundle on `/` by setting the `publicPath` in **./app.js**.

```
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: '/'
}))
```

You also don't need to serve anything on `/build`. But if you want to use it to test the built bundle from your actual file system, you would need to run Webpack to generate that bundle. For that to work correctly you need to correct your `BUILD_DIR` to:

```
var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './build');
```

The reason is that `path.resolve` treats `/build` as an absolute path and doesn't add it to the current directory. Which would also throw a permission denied error unless you run it as root. For more information see: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths

Comment: Do you know anything about nested routes? I have almost the exact same setup but when I try hitting something like: '/test' Node either can't find index.html or 'Cannot GET /test'. I'm using React / browserHistory  in the front end

Comment: @user2465134 You need to serve `/index.html` for these routes, for example by serving it when no other route was matched. But you have to make sure that you don't accidentally serve it instead of your JavaScript or any assets. This is called History API fallback and there exist plugins/middleware that can handle that for you.

Comment: Michael, could you please look at my post here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259027/dev-mode-for-node-webpack-dev-server-react-no-such-file-or-directory-for-nes/47259971#47259971. It shows my setup and can give you a little more context

Comment: Michael, I use History API Fallback and I have wildcard route that should send index.html. Since index.html is in memory via webpack-dev-server, History API Fallback should serve it but it doesn't seem to