# Dev Mode for Node, Webpack-Dev-Server, React - No Such File or Directory for Nested Routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to get my application to work in development mode with Node and Webpack-Dev-Server. When I serve up '/' I get back exactly what I intend. However, when I do '/test' I get 'no such file or directory'. I have read a lot of documentation on Webpack's website and React Router Training, none seem to really answer this issue. I want to be able to use browserHistory instead of hashHistory (I am still using React-Router v3).

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production npm run clean && webpack -p",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.1.8",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.1",
    "react-router": "^3.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.2.0-rc.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.20.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const VENDOR_LIBS = [
  'axios', 'react', 'redux', 'react-dom', 'react-redux',
  'react-router', 'redux-promise'
];

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './client/src/index.js',
    vendor: VENDOR_LIBS
  },
  output: {
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        test: /\.css$/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {limit: 40000}
          },
          'image-webpack-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './client/src/index.html'
    })
  ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: '/dist',
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
};
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();


if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
  const webpack = require('webpack');
  const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
  const config = require('./webpack.config.js');
  const compiler = webpack(config);
  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath
  }));
} else {
  app.use(express.static('dist'));
}

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3050, () => console.log('Listening'));
```

routes.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/app';
import Home from './components/home';

const componentRoutes = (
  <Route component={App} path='/'>
    <Route component={Home} path='/test' />
  </Route>
);

const Routes = () => {
  return <Router history={ browserHistory } routes={ componentRoutes } />
};

export default Routes;
```

The App component renders a single div saying it loaded and same for the Home component. If you care to see the entire thing on Github, here is a link:

https://github.com/jlag34/nodeWebpackSupport

The main goal is to be able to load '/test' in dev mode without using hashHistory.

Wepback docs: https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are serving `dist/index.html` when no other route was matched, with:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});
```

But this looks for that file on your file system, which should work in your production build (when you build the bundle and then serve it). If you look at the error you get when going to `/test` you will see that this file doesn't exist.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/path/to/nodeWebpackSupport/dist/index.html'
```

This happens, because you're generating the `index.html` with `html-webpack-plugin` and `webpack-dev-middleware` keeps that in memory and doesn't write it to the file system. In development you cannot serve that file, but instead you need to serve the one from memory. You can access the files in webpack's memory with `compiler.outputFileSystem.readFile`.

In your development routes you need to add the following (originally taken from the [comment of `html-webpack-plugin` #145](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/145#issuecomment-170554832)):

```
app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
  const filename = path.resolve(compiler.outputPath, 'index.html');
  compiler.outputFileSystem.readFile(filename, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.set('content-type','text/html');
    res.send(result);
    res.end();
  });
});
```

Comment: This does remove the error and will serve up my page when I hit '/test', however, it isn't displaying the correct component. If you look at route.js when you hit '/test' it should serve the Home component but with your solution App is being displayed

Comment: Oh you are right. You're using nested routes, and I think in react-router v3 you need to explicitly render `props.children` in the outer route (`app.js` in your case).

Comment: changed it and it worked fine. i knew this.. lol anyways, thanks SO SO SO much

Comment: Thank you a bunch. Was cracking my head couple of hours with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

> The main goal is to be able to load '/test' in dev mode without using hashHistory.

`React-router` type as `static`, `browser`, `hash` and so one can be easily selected by generative jsx-function, which is selected by control flow or `webpack` predefined constants. Such technique is used for SSR (server-side rendering), when `jsx` with applied routes is returned, dependent on environment.

```
const RootComponent = () => {/* root component */};
const EntryPoint = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? (props) => (<BrowserRouter><RootComponent {...props} /></BrowserRouter>)
    : (props) => (<HashRouter><RootComponent {...props} /></HashRouter>)
export default EntryPoint
```

Comment: I said that I didn't want to use hash history but your solution uses it...

Comment: @user2465134 Of course answer above is about to configure `react-router` dependent on `webpack` mode in general case. It can be `BrowserRouter` in any case, but with different parameters, e.g. if your production façade supports specific URL routing. Also, it's useful for `SSR` to configure `StaticRouter` on it